# Cannot get an Array of ArrayList of PVectors to work

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, processing

For some reason, the Processing editor is giving me a `The class "Vectors" does not exist` ... what am I missing?

```
int num_gradations = 100;

ArrayList[] AllGradation = new ArrayList[num_gradations];
ArrayList<PVector> Vectors = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(700, 700, P2D);
  smooth(8);
  randomSeed(20);

  for (int l = 0; l>num_gradations; l++) {
    AllGradation[l] = new Vectors();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Vectors` is a variable not a type

Comment: Uhg. Duh. Thank you. answering my own question...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
int num_gradations = 100;

ArrayList[] AllGradation = new ArrayList[num_gradations];

void setup() {
  size(700, 700, P2D);
  smooth(8);
  randomSeed(20);

  for (int l = 0; l>num_gradations; l++) {
    AllGradation[l] = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  }
}
```